# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given on line 101

Tags: php, mysqli

Im not sure why I'm getting this error. Line 101 shows as:

```
$sql_apr_i="SELECT SUM(total) FROM invoices WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date_added) = 06 AND estimate = 0 AND user_id = '$user_id'";
$data_apr_i = mysqli_query($connect_db,$sql_apr_i);
$april_invoice = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_april_i);
```

What am i doing wrong to get this error?

Comment: I see this question a lot. Please read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: Have you checked `mysqli_error($connect_db);` or even `var_dump($connect_db);` to make sure you've actually got a connection to your database?

Comment: You are not debugging your code properly, nor are you using existing tools (google comes to mind). You're also not trying to figure it out on your own, something every beginner should be doing. Please do some basic research before asking such a question. Many people before you had it, the solution is **always the same**.

Comment: Since it's obvious that your data is associated with a month, check your spelling.

Comment: Its connecting to the database properly @EliasVanOotegem

Comment: Thanks @JasonMcCreary for the debugging link, ill definitely use that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong variable name passed to mysqli_fetch_assoc. Try this:

```
$sql_apr_i = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM invoices WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date_added) = 06 AND estimate = 0 AND user_id = '$user_id'";  
$data_apr_i = mysqli_query($connect_db, $sql_apr_i);  
$april_invoice = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_apr_i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$sql_apr_i="SELECT SUM(total) FROM invoices WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date_added) = 06 AND estimate = 0 AND user_id = '$user_id'";
$data_apr_i = mysqli_query($connect_db,$sql_apr_i);
$april_invoice = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_april_i); // Look at the difference
```

to:

```
$sql_apr_i="SELECT SUM(total) AS totalSum FROM invoices WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date_added) = 06 AND estimate = 0 AND user_id = '$user_id'";
$data_apr_i = mysqli_query($connect_db,$sql_apr_i);
$april_invoice = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_apr_i); //Wrong variable here
```

**Updated** the query there was an error in there aswell

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add alias for Sum like the following:

```
SELECT SUM(total) as TotalSum FROM invoices 
WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date_added) = 06 AND estimate = 0 AND user_id = '$user_id'
```